# How do I send file specific parameter in uploadSuccess of S3 FineUploader

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am using S3 FineUploader 5.3 to upload files to a Bucket but on success I want to send an extra size parameter to server for the file for which the endpoint is being called I tried using the below approach but this did not work.

```
 uploadSuccess: {
                    endpoint: 'breeze/s3/success',
                    params: {
                        'UserData': JSON.stringify(config.userLogin),
                        'size': function (fileId) {
                            return uploader.getSize(fileId);
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any parameters you associate with the file will be sent to your server with the upload success request as well. You can specify file parameters via [the `setParams` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setParams) or [the `request.params` configuration option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request.params).